# Managing AWS credentials separately and accessing those in java code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, credentials

I am using java to upload and download files from s3. My problem is that I can't check in the code along with the secret and access key to public but the code has to checked in to a public environment. How can I manage my credentials separately and access only its references in my code?

the code I used is

```
String awsAccessKey = "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY";
String awsSecretKey = "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY";
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = 
    new AWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
```

I want the credentials manager to be platform independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement an [`AWSCredentialsProvider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html), which is an interface for supplying credentials to SDK clients. For example the [`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) is an implementation which looks in multiple places for credentials (the environment, a properties file, and EC2 instance profile).

You can check out the implementation of several credentials providers in the AWS SDK for Java [Github repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth).

Comment: To add to the AWSCredentialsProvider mechanism, the most secured way of providing the actual credentials to the machine running your code is to use IAM Roles (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-roles.html). NEVER write credentials in any source code that you might share with others.

Comment: Here is a link to a best practices on using credentials with AWS Java SDK: http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx27W1S3VWL232L/Credentials-Best-Practices

Answer (score 0):

All amazon utilities require these properties to be defined using environment variables, you can use the same approach, or use a file based configuration.

Comment: I need to dynamically get the key from a manager in an automation suite... I'm not running it locally so i cant set my environment variables.

Comment: you can either define the keys in to running systems environment, or define keys in config file http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/ has a great library to read such files